# DomPdf not displaying dynamic images only displaying single image

Tags: php, joomla, dompdf

I am creating print membership card based on Joomla users, after generating membershipcard it need to print as pdf, the problem was single image displaying in domp pdf correctly , but multiple image not displaying only showing single image at all the time ,

default.php

```
<form method='POST' action='index.php?option=com_mycomponentbs&view=MembershipCard&task=cardpdf'>
<?php foreach($orderitems as $re) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' class="checkbox1" name='id[]' id="id" value="<?php echo $re->id?>">
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $re->id?></td> <td><?php echo $re->name?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
```

cardpdf.php

```
foreach ($orderitems as $re):
  $user = JFactory::getUser();
  $path = JURI::Root().'back.jpeg';
  $font_path="Lin.ttf";
  $card = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
  $white = imagecolorallocate($card, 255, 255, 255);
  imagettftext($card, 22, 0, 40, 515, $white, $font_path, $re->id);
  $file= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'tmpl/back1.jpeg';

  ImageGIF($card, $filenametemp);
  $ImageData = file_get_contents($filenametemp);
  $ImageDataEnc = base64_encode($ImageData);
  unlink($filenametemp); // delete the file
  ?>

  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,<?=$ImageDataEnc1?>>
  </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; } ?>
```

```

Comment: Welcome to Stackovefrflow. Show us what you did so far.

Comment: Edit your question adding code and don't forget to format it properly. Otherwise people will downvote you and nobody will help.

Comment: Also spend at least a few moments to format your code. Nobody wants to try to decipher a one-liner.

Comment: Is that your actual code in use? You're closing a table row inside the loop but not opening one. That's probably not what you want. I doubt it would cause your problem, but your layout is going to be all wrong.

Comment: Also, cardpdf.php uses $ImageDataEnc1 in the image tag, shouldn't that be $ImageDataEnc? [edited]

Comment: allright, BrainS, it working correctly, thanks for your efforts

Comment: Feel free to post the solution as an answer for others to find.